# How I can select UI elements inside sketch symbols for Invision Craft Prototype Tool?

Tags: sketch-app, mobile, prototyping

I can't apply links in elements that are inside of a symbol. I don't want detach them from symbols so how I can put these elements selectable for Craft Prototype tool? 
Here's example for tab app menu:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way I've found to do this currently is create a rectangle with no fill or stroke over the area you want to be the activated button. Then link that rectangle instead of the item below that sits inside a style.